# How to hide popup alert dialog box of Bluetooth pairing while connecting with HC-05 Bluetooth module?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

I want to implement an app which connects with HC-05 Bluetooth module. While connecting with HC-05 Bluetooth module an popup of alert dialog box which ask for password comes for 3-4 seconds and disappears but it connects successfully. I want to hide alert box which comes for 3-4 seconds. How to solve it?

[Dialog box which appears while connecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzjzP.png)

[After connecting to module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25t14.png)

Comment: Do you connect to your HC-05 programmatically ? And which purpose has your second screenshot ?

Comment: Yup.. I connected HC-05 module programmatically. Second screenshot shows dialog box disappers after 2-3 seconds.

Comment: Do you have a Broadcast Receiver listening for [`ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST) ? If so, can you share the related code ?